# user profile from XMPP iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, xmpp

I am using XMPP for chatting in my iPhone application, I need to retrieve the profile of every user in buddy list, like phone number, street address etc.

How can I get started?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous, are you using a xmpp library?

Comment: i heard XEP-054 extension can be used for Vcard..please help me how can i do it,

Comment: XEP-0054 is now coming along with the xmpp framwork , we can download it from [XMPP](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [XEP-54](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html) can be used for this purpose, PLEASE do not spam the network by making `vcard-temp` requests for everyone on your roster every time your client logs in.  Since you haven't told us what client library you're using, all we can do is provide you with the protocol you need to send:

```
<iq id='v1'
    type='get'>
  <vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/>
</iq>
```

Note that XEP-54 is about to be obsoleted by [XEP-292](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0292.html), but it will take several years for that transition to take place.

Comment: thank you for your reply. but i want the vcard when i am going to chat with that user.I got this xmpp frame work from code.google.com..it contain some extensions like XEP-082 XEP-0203..etc..but where can i find XEP-0054, and how can i include  XEP-0045 in my code, what are the changes i need in code...please help me

Comment: what is the *name* of the library?

Comment: thank you joe i solved the problem we need to create a req of the above form and send it `- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq` will receive the Vcard of user

Comment: So, you're using XMPPFramework (http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/)?  Please be careful that the IQ you receive has the same ID as the one you sent, and is from the JID you expect, in order to avoid a poisoning attack.  Also, make sure you return YES in your delegate if and *only* if you're going to process the IQ.